# close .NET application before uninstalling

Tags: .net, windows-installer

I've inherited an existing .NET application (C#) which consists of a windows service and a controlling GUI.
The GUI application, the service and the setup project are embedded in a vs2010 solution.
The GUI is a windows Form which is launched by a static main class, because it has to reside in the tray when minimized.
The GUI has a timer which periodically checks if the service is active and enables/disables the popup menu "start service" and "stop service" entries accordingly.
The problem is that when I try to uninstall, the service is removed before the GUI and the timer_Tick in the GUI throws an exception because it doesn't find the service.
Here is the code used by the main class to start the application:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Punto di ingresso principale dell'applicazione.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new frmMain());
    }
}
```

The code executed by the timer (the try/catch block was added by me to catch the exception):

```
private void tmrCheckService_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceController service = new ServiceController("MyService");
            if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                startToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                startToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
            }

            service = null;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException oEx)
        {
            //tmrCheckService.Stop();
            //this.Close();
        }
    }
```

If I uncomment the code in the catch block, the application quits and the uninstall succeeds.
I'm not sure this is the best way to manage the error. I'd prefer to manage the uninstall process, making the GUI to be stopped and removed before the service is removed, but I can't find a way to do that.
A possible solution I've thought is to override the on beforeuninstall method of the service installer, find the process attached to my GUI application and kill it programmatically. If this solution is better, how could I achieve it?
Thank you.

Comment: In a "multiple users logged onto the same machine" scenario (e.g. if fast user switching is enabled, or remote desktops, etc), could there be *multiple* instances of the GUI application running?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever:
nothing prevents that from happening, but it's not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have uninstalled the service then an exception is likely.. An exception you will need to handle. you're only other option is some form of uninstall notification from the service to the ui but that seems overly complex. Just handle any exception and tidy up any resources